# Nsstring convert to const char remove quotes

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsstring

I have a trouble with quotes after convert from NSString to const char*
i have an sql query in NSString like
**INSERT INTO table VALUES("one","two","three")**
for sqlite3_exec i need a cons char, i tried to convert string via
    [queryS UTF8String]
or
    [queryS Cstring]
but it remove all quotes from text and it looks like
 **INSERT INTO table VALUES(one,two,three)**
how i can make a const char from NSString with quotes?

Comment: please post the relevant code.

Comment: show us some code. the method you used is correct and doesnt remove quotes itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you escaping the NSString ?
I just executed this:

```
NSString* queryS = @"INSERT INTO table VALUES(\"one\",\"two\",\"three\")";
NSLog(@"%@", queryS);

const char* st = [queryS UTF8String];
NSLog(@"%s", st);
```

And got this:

```
2012-11-27 09:08:09.926 INSERT INTO table VALUES("one","two","three")
2012-11-27 09:08:09.926 INSERT INTO table VALUES("one","two","three")
```